# Data Shifted Over for Specific Columns in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL, my question is I had some trouble importing data which led to some discrepancy.

```
Column A    Column B       Column C  Column D  Column E   Column F 
WB-002      "Brown Sales"  14A       140000    12/5/2015  12/5/2016          
WB-002      "Johnson       Inc"      24B       150000     12/5/2015,2/5/2016
WB-005      "Sonoma        Inc"      26C       300000     7/30/2015,7/30/2016
```

How would I be able to shift the data over one for the rows affected past column 1? Or would I have to replace each rows data with the next row over and over again? Final result wanted:

```
Column A    Column B       Column C  Column D  Column E   Column F 
WB-002      "Brown Sales"  14A       140000    12/5/2015  12/5/2016          
WB-002      "Johnson Inc"  24B       150000    12/5/2015  2/5/2016
WB-005      "Sonoma  Inc"  26C       300000    7/30/2015 7/30/2016
```

Comment: In my experience, it's way easier to truncate and rerun your import. Is that an option? Because writing a query to parse through your dirty data is going to be... not fun.

Comment: Seems it's not about SQL. Look like you are trying to import data to CSV file. If so, post your SQL data first.

Comment: @JacobH Given the comments and foreshadowing what's going to come, seems like I rather just re-import and try again

Comment: @RomanMaksimov Might be misunderstanding your question - but the data in the post is from SQL. I imported data from a CSV as a flat file and this is how SQL read it as.

Comment: You see, the problem with you origin CSV file. The easiest way is to fix that CSV file and re-import data to the SQL.

Comment: Made some edits to fix some discrepancies in my final wanted table.

Comment: When you import, choose double quotes " as your Text Qualifier on your flat file source connection (under General). That should fix it.

Comment: THANK YOU! @JacobH

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

I don't think SQL Server understands the real CSV format (unless more recent versions have seen improvements in this regard).  Alas.  You should try re-importing the data (okay fingers, don't type Postgres which does understand CSV).

If the file is small enough, then load it into Excel and save it with tab delimiters -- or something that is not a comma.  Then you can bring it into SQL Server correctly.

If it is larger, I'm not sure what to do (I guess when I've faced this problem, Excel has always come to the rescue).  Depending on your skills, you could pre-process in a language such as Python, grep, or PowerShell.  Or you could load each line into SQL Server as a string and then do all the parsing in SQL (not trivial either).

In the meantime, let Microsoft know that the most common export format from their Excel product should be able to be imported into their database product.

Comment: So my data is about 3000 rows long, and I am familiar with R - is there a way to import the data in from R into SQL Server? Or would 3000 be consider small enough to go with the first solution?

Comment: @S31 . . . I would expect that somewhere in the vast library of R routines, there is something that reads real CSV.  However, 3000 is trivial for Excel so you can do that in a minute or so.